# jQuery returns object with length attribute undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I was checking if some elements exist with:

```
if ($(selector).length > 0){
....
}
```

However, sometimes the returned object (even if the element exists in the DOM and has returned) does not have the length attribute so this never evaluates to true. 
This error appears in chrome.
Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Edit:
I use this code:

```
var variable;
for(let elem in selectors){ 
    if($(elem).length > 0){
      variable = true;
      break;
    }
    else
      variable = false;
  }
```

Given a list of selectors, `variable` is true if at least one of the selectors exists. This is inside a google chrome extension's content script. After this code runs in the plugin I get the same problem even in the console of google chrome.

Edit:
This code does not create a problem:

```
var variable;
    if($(elem).length > 0){
      variable = true;

    }
    else
      variable = false;
```

It seams that the problem is the `for` loop or/and the `break;` statement. However, a for loop is needed to make this code work for a list of selectors and not just for one.

Comment: If you could post your selector and a snippet of the DOM that your trying to select that would be helpful.

Comment: You might have `$` defined as something other than jquery (eg if using WordPress site).  Try `if (jQuery(selector).length > 0)`

Comment: @freedomn-m
`>>jQuery('nav.guest-nav')`
_VM117086:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)_

Comment: So, you're not using jquery.  **" This is inside a google chrome extension's context script"**

Comment: @freedomn-m what should i use then? because I have some other issues with jQuery. however, i want to make some ajax calls in the background scripts. so not so many options i guess

Comment: The google chrome extension documentation shows how to load jquery

Comment: I have been using jquery in other parts without major problems. for example in this case if I don't use the $( ) inside a for loop then there is no problem.

Comment: That's because that's **javascript**, not *jquery*.  Specifically chrome extension javascript.   If *jQuery is not defined* then you don't have jquery.

Answer (score 1):

It seams that the `document.querySelectorAll()` does not create the same problem and works as expected. So I used this one instead of the $(). If you only want to check if an element exists it is working just fine. 
So this code always returns true if at least one of the selectors exists in the web page:

```
function exists(selectors){
   var selectorExists = false;
   for(let i=0; i < selectors.length; i++){ 
      let element = document.querySelectorAll(selectors[i]);
      if(element.length > 0){
         selectorExists = true;
         break;
      }
    }
   return selectorExists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is because html is not loaded then we can use timeout

now what i understood from code is you are using for loop for selectors so selectors should come as array not the element within it (elem here) is not array so how elem will have length??

```
setTimeout(function(){
if ($(selector).length > 0){
for(let elem in selectors){ 
if($(elem)){
  variable = true;
  break;
}
else
  variable = false;
}
}
},100);
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I get the same error as when using the for loop.

Comment: hi ze
 in console when you are trying $(selector) what is coming is it html element or an array of html element

Comment: html element, which is not an array we cannot iterate if we get an array of html element then we can iterate.